# I want to change the location of my factories, how can I make Rails know the new location when generating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, factory-bot

I'm using `rails 3.2.0.rc1` and `factory_girl_rails`

I want the location of my factories to be `RAILS_ROOT/factories` instead of `RAILS_ROOT/specs/factories`

When I use the Rails generators, I know it creates default factories, how can I inform Rails where it should place them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

factory_girl_rails configures the app generators with the specs/factories path. See

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails/blob/master/lib/factory_girl_rails/railtie.rb#L11

You can override this in an initializer:

```
YourAppName::Application.config.app_generators do |g|
  g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, :dir => 'factories'
end
```